# How to get the id of a build association in a method of an object being built

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, reactivevalidatedobject

I have this code:

```
bar = Bar.new
bar.build_foo
```

And in foo model I have:

```
validates :baz, :presence => true, :if lambda { self.bar.terminal.is_active == true }
```

In the lambda self.bar is nil I understand that but is there any way to get the association bar in the lambda block?

Comment: try: `if: lambda {|record| record.bar }`

Comment: I tried it - it is still nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the inverse associations:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :foo, inverse_of: :bar
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar, inverse_of: :foo
end
```